# Fee for statement of comparability

Tags: working-visas, germany

I applied for statement of comparability to Zab and they asked me to pay the fee like 200€. I want to ask that how can i pay it? Like which bank. Ive gone to UBL and they said that they dont know any kind of procedure like this. Please help me out. And second thing is ive sent my two degrees B. Com and Masters so should ive to pay 300€?

Comment: Is there no option to pay by credit/debit card?

Comment: They have given all details like bank name account details but no bank here in pakistan is willing to transfer money. Im really worried about it.